# how to keep cookies persistent all the time for requests.session in python

Tags: python, session, python-requests

i am using python requests to get some information from company site,
first, i need to login, then use beautifulsoup to get some other url, and go to these url to get information,

i use session, but now the problem is:
after i login,get the url, then go to these url, and find the text return from these url is not what i want, not sure whether it is because of non-persistent cookies,

```
s = requests.session()
s.post(url = "https://login.company.com/login/login.do",data={'uid':user,'password':
password,'actionFlag': 'loginAuthenticate'})
r=s.get("http://3ms.company.com/hi/space/?l=zh-cn")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
div=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'top_pop mt10'})
for a in div.find_all('li'):
    url=a.find('div',attrs={'class':'top_pop_P_right fn'}).find('a')['href']
    r1=s.get(url)
    print(r1.text)
```

i try to use the following codes to update cookies, but do not work,

```
if r1.cookies.get_dict():
  s.cookies.update(r1.cookies)
```

any idea on how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: did you chech the result of the login? I assume you did not login successfully. often you have to first get the login page (In order to get some session cookie and some kind of csrf token (as cookie and as form value)

Often you have to extract the csrf token and add it to your post.

I suggest you use your web browser in debug mode (F12 for firefox, click then on network) and you look at the received and transmitted cookies and at all values, that were posted)

Comment: after the first post, the first get method return the successful result, the problem happen on the second get method in for loop,

Comment: I must admit this is weird. If it works for the first get it should work for the second one.

Can you print the urls in the for loop and try the same urls in a web browser.

Comment: when i get the url from for loop, and try them directly in a web browser directly, it works fine, the only problem is: the url i get is: http://3ms.company.com/hi/space/3542, after i paste it into a browser, it will redirect to http://3ms.company.com/Ufield/z00102212?l=zh-cn,

Comment: cookies in a session should auto-update normally you do not need to call s.cookies.update()

I'm running out of ideas perhaps somebody else can help.
Without having the real url and a real user account (can be a test account) I cannot reproduce and analyze the issue